# parse jpeg binary file

Tags: c#, jpeg, decode

I exploring internet for two days and still can't find a good head start for this. I want to write a code with c# to get a .jpeg binary file and decode it and display the image. everywhere I looked there is lots of explanation about jpeg algorithm but still I can't find good explanation about how to parse and decode this file. I mean for example how can I know Huffman DC table starts with what number and end's with what number?
I appreciate if someone can link me somewhere that I can find explanation about parsing binary jpeg file.
thank you and sorry for my english.

Comment: Whats wrong with `Image.FromFile()` ?

Comment: If all you want to do is display it, .NET supports JPEGs already.  Whatever you'd be decoding it to would have to use the same API that already supports JPEGs.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: If this is a learning project, what point is there in asking for the solution? If this is not a learning project, why aren't you using `Image.FromFile()`?

Comment: Well, try harder then. Try the different parts of the algorithm before trying to decode the JPEG itself. Can you build a Huffman tree? Can you rebuild the original data from that? Can you implement DCT? The headers are well documented even on wikipedia (the whole process is there in fact).

Comment: Sure - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG. It has everything you need. :)

Comment: You can take a look on what exist elsewhere: https://code.google.com/p/fjcore/source/browse/trunk/FJCore/Decoder/JpegDecoder.cs?r=2

Comment: is this something you want to do as a learning exercise? If so, it is a learning experience worth doing. However, it takes A LOT of effort. When I went down that path nearly 20 years ago, everyone said just use a library. Now at least there is a book explaining it http://www.amazon.com/Compressed-Image-File-Formats-JPEG/dp/0201604434/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1429123264&sr=8-1&keywords=jpeg . When I learned all this, the only book out there on the subject was theoretical and of not much use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trust me, it isn't something you can do. I wouldn't touch the thing with a pole long various meters...

http://ijg.org/

Here there is the site of:

> IJG is an informal group that writes and distributes a widely used free library for JPEG image compression. The first version was released on 7-Oct-1991.

There is the source code for libjpeg.

if you just want to take a look, here http://elm-chan.org/fsw/tjpgd/00index.html there is the source of

> TJpgDec is a generic JPEG image decompressor module that highly optimized for small embedded systems.

it is even

> Platform independent. Written in ANSI-C.

Being tiny it will be probably easy to reimplement in C# :-)

Comment: Making a good JPG is hard, and involves quite a few heuristics. Reading any JPG isn't - it's actually rather straightforward. The compression is usually far harder than the decompression (note how there's still better and better compression while the format remains the same, and can be read by 10 year old routines).

Comment: @Luaan Still, I wouldn't touch it with a pole long various meters :-) It is doable but very difficult, and (for me) useless, because your library would decompress only "barebone" jpegs, not the various sub-formats that exist... CMYK Jpeg?

Comment: Oh, I'm not saying it's *practical* :D But I'm still the guy who wrote his own operating system (and virtual CPU... and real CPU... and...), so I do understand the drive to understand "mysterious" systems. As long as you throw the code away when you're done, it doesn't hurt to build up some extra skills along the way :))

Comment: @Luaan I'm more of the practical side... If it can be done in a day, then I do love to explore it... Otherwise not :-)

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree. It's just that a lot of things can be done in a day if you build it the right way, building on the knowledge (and work) you already have. I'm way too lazy to actually do anything that takes more than a day :D